# Minipage is not working properly

Tags: minipage, wrapfigure

I am trying to draw a figure on the right and some text on the left (I have defined a `lemma` environment in my preamble, it is working everywhere in my code). This is my code:

```
There are some other formulae for inradius which requires the following lemma, which gives the distances of the points of contact of incircle and sides from the vertices.
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!20]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\noindent
\begin{lemma}
In $\Delta ABC$ let $D,E$, and $F$ be the points of contact of incircle with the sides $BC,CA$ and $AB$ respectively as shown in figure, then we have
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{array}{ccc}
AE  & = & AF=s-a \\
BD  & =  & BF= s-b\\
 CD  & =  & CE=  s-c   
\end{array}
\right\}
\label{101020eq02}
\end{equation}
\end{lemma}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{SoTFig16.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
```

This code is throwing an error `Not in outer par mode`. How can I remove the error? Is there an better way to get the desired output? I tried `wrapfigure` too but it did not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figures are "floating objects" (meant to migrate to a different place on the page or on subsequent pages) and can't be put in a minipage. Since there is no caption, you probably don't want a "figure", but just `\includegraphics`.

You also have an error with two minipages of `0.5\textwidth`, with no allowance for the space between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed,amsmath,amsthm,graphicx,xcolor}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
Figures are ``floating objects'' and can't be put in a minipage. 
Since there is no caption, you probably don't want a ``figure'' 
but just \verb|\includegraphics|.
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!20]
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{lemma}
In $\Delta ABC$ let $D,E$, and $F$ be the points of contact of in circle
with the sides $BC,CA$ and $AB$ respectively as shown in figure, then we have
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{array}{ccc}
AE  & = & AF=s-a \\
BD  & =  & BF= s-b\\
 CD  & =  & CE=  s-c   
\end{array}
\right\}
\label{101020eq02}
\end{equation}
\end{lemma}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Why did you tag "wrapfigure"? was it just to get me to read the question?
You could probably use it, but there is no benefit in this example.

Comment: I used `wrapfigure` because I thought there would be some better way by using `wrapfigure`.